# When opening minecraft launcher A small window opens with "unknown error"

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-launcher

I have just bought Minecraft from minecraft.net. I downloaded the installer "minecraftinstaller.msi" and installed it. Then I tried to open the minecraft launcher, but when I did that a window opened with the text "unknown error". I have no idea why this happens. I have tried to remove java and install it again but it did not work. I have a Windows Vista with 3GB RAM. Is that not enough to run Minecraft? Have I wasted my money?

Comment: Vista with 3GB RAM should run Minecraft, although it's not exactly a gaming computer. Are there any other error messages (like an error code or something)?

Comment: No none. But I have downloaded the old launcher and now it works, still haven;t figured out about the new launcher though

Comment: are you running any other version e.g. tekkit classic

Comment: I think so, not sure actually. How do I know that?

Comment: Have you tried to erase .minecraft folder in ÷APPDATA÷ ?

Comment: I have tried it but it didn't work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The Minecraft installer is a new feature.** It was introduced to remove the hassle of manually setting up Minecraft, but it may have some quirks that make it stop working on certain machines.

Nevertheless, there is an alternative way to install Minecraft:

- Head over to the [Minecraft download site](https://minecraft.net/download) and download the file *Minecraft.exe*
- Open the file browser and navigate to your personal directory
- Create a new directory called *Minecraft* and place the downloaded file *Minecraft.exe* in there
- Rightclick the *Minecraft.exe* and select *create shortcut*. That creates a shortcut that you can drag onto your desktop.
- Double click the shortcut to start Minecraft

I hope that works for you! If not, please leave a comment with further details.

Comment: Have done exactly what you said, but I still get a window with the unknown error. I noticed that eversince i got a new file in the directory called "nativelog". This is what it says.

Comment: Failed to download manifest
Failed to start application .\runtime\jre-x32\\bin\java.exe -cp "game\launcher.jar" net.minecraft.launcher.Main

Comment: That probably means there is something wrong with the bundled Java version. Try downloading the file *Minecraft.exe* in the section *Minecraft for Windows (alternative)*.

Comment: Thanks man! It works just fine now. Really appreciated the time and effort you put into solving this problem. Have a nice day!